# Creation of file-format in Snow-flake

Tags: ascii, delimiter, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, file-format

I am new to SF. I have a typical problem that I have faced while loading some data. The delimiter is part of extended ascii. It does not come in 0-127. We use thorn (ascii - 254) as delimiter. My Qn is while specifying the delimiter can I give the ascii code of that delimiter instead of actual character (44 instead of comma, 9 instead of tab etc)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the hex/octal code of any valid Unicode delimiter in the `FIELD_DELIMITER` option of the File Format. [From the documentation](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html#format-type-options-formattypeoptions):

> The specified delimiter must be a valid UTF-8 character and not a random sequence of bytes.
>
> For example, for fields delimited by the thorn (Þ) character, specify the octal (\336) or hex (0xDE) value. Also accepts a value of NONE.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  But as per the doc, it is expecting a character

i.e.
FIELD_DELIMITER = '<character>' | NONE

Comment: @user6892348 no you can use the hex or octal representation of the char too. Put `FIELD_DELIMITER = 0xDE` and see if it works. `0xDE` is the hex code for the thorn char in UTF-8 encoding. You just need to make sure you've set the `ENCODING` correctly depending on the source file's encoding.